# MS Access, vba if then else condition not working "runtime error 438"

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am creating a button to validate the fields that have null values in MS Access forms. I am not able to understand what is wrong with the below if then else condtion. It is not working as expected. Any help much appreciate. Thanks in advance!

Below is the error

```
runtime error 438: object doesn't support this property or method
```

Code:

```
Private Sub Command1008_Click()
    
 If IsNull(Me!Netzwerk) Then
    Me!Netzwerk.BackColor = vbRed
 Else
    Me!Netzwerk.BackColor = vbWhite
 End If
 
 If IsNull(Me!Interesse) Then
    Me!Interesse.BackColor = vbRed
 Else
    Me!Interesse.BackColor = vbWhite
 End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Are controls also named Netzwerk and Interesse? Use `Me.` instead of `Me!`. Conditional Formatting could set backcolor  for textbox or combobox and no VBA needed. I always give controls names different from fields, like: tbxNetzwerk and tbxInteresse.

Comment: Your syntax is correct, and the code is verifiable. However, the controls must, of course, support the `BackColor` property, which texboxes do, also when named as the field they might be bound to. If the controls are textboxes, perhaps these are _not_ named `Netzwerk` and `Interesse`.